# [Kinect] About sound streaming

Tags: ros, kinect, web, beginner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I want to know if there is any libray that allows ROS to stream over the web the microphone of the kinect, something like the `web_video_server`.

Update:
Navigating through the forum I found the library `audio_common`, it is posible to generate an audio stream from this library and the rosbridge `Websocket`?

Thanks beforehand!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/204425/%5Bkinect%5D-about-sound-streaming/) by [pexison](https://answers.ros.org/users/21144/pexison/) on ROS Answers with karma: 82 on 2015-03-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you expand the main idea of [audio_common tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/audio_common/Tutorials/Remotely%20listening%20through%20robot%20ears) out of the localhost space, you are able to stream sound.

---

Originally posted by [pexison](https://answers.ros.org/users/21144/pexison/) with karma: 82 on 2015-03-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0